# Python pandas: removing rows not matching multiple conditions from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a column using pandas.dataframe like so:

```
index  fruits    origin      attribute
 1     apple     USA         tasty
 2     apple     France      yummy
 3     apple     USA         juicy
 4     apple     England     juicy
 5     apple     Japan       normal
 6     banana    Canada      nice
 7     banana    Italy       good
 .....
```

I want to select `yummy apple from France(2)` and remove unmatching `apples` from table like the following:

```
index  fruits    origin      attribute
 1     apple     France      yummy
 2     banana    Canada      nice
 3     banana    Italy       good
 .....
```

I thought the following should work. But it doesn't:

```
df.drop(df[(df.fruits == "apple") & (df.origin != "France") | (df.fruits == "apple") & (df.attribute != "yummy")].index)
```

Then I tried the following which also doesn't work:

```
df = df[~df[(df.fruits == "apple") & (df.origin != "France") & (df.attribute != "yummy")]
```

Any help, lads?

Comment: @Kevin Yan thanks for making my question more readable!

Comment: You can use shortcut key CTL+k on PC or CMD+k on Mac to quickly format code segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If select by matching condition:

```
df[(df.fruits != 'apple') | ((df.fruits == 'apple') & (df.origin == 'France') & (df.attribute == 'yummy'))]

#index  fruits  origin  attribute
#1  2    apple  France      yummy
#5  6   banana  Canada       nice
#6  7   banana   Italy       good
```

---

If remove by non-matching condition: what needs to be removed are rows where `fruits` is apple but `origin` doesn't match `France` or `attribute` doesn't match `yummy`:

```
df[~((df.fruits == 'apple') & ((df.origin != 'France') | (df.attribute != 'yummy')))]

# index fruits  origin  attribute
#1    2  apple  France      yummy
#5    6 banana  Canada       nice
#6    7 banana   Italy       good
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.query(
    'fruits == "apple" & origin == "France" & attribute == "yummy"'
).append(df.query('fruits != "apple"'))

       fruits  origin attribute
index                          
2       apple  France     yummy
6      banana  Canada      nice
7      banana   Italy      good
```